# Which 2019 technologies were correctly predicted by Blade Runner?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, prediction

We’re finally in **2019**, the year in which *[Blade Runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner)* — Ridley Scott’s iconic 1982 science fiction film — is set.

**Which technologies that exist in 2019 (at least as prototypes) were correctly predicted by *Blade Runner*?**

[image: movie screenshot, woman's face projected on building]

To clarify, I am looking only for technologies that were not in existence at the time that *Blade Runner* was made.  (All technologies that appear in *Blade Runner* are relevant, regardless of whether they also appear in other works.)

(These are the same requirements as in a similar question regarding *[Back to the Future II](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95971/)*.)

**Update:** Six months after asking this, on the [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20191111-are-we-living-in-a-blade-runner-world).

Comment: Do [AI sex robots](https://abcnews.go.com/Nightline/video/buy-sex-robot-equipped-artificial-intelligence-20000-54712355) count?

Comment: @Valorum yes, in binary.

Comment: [*"Electrogonorrhea, the noisy killer"*](https://vimeo.com/12915013)

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.cnn.com/cnn/2018/12/28/movies/blade-runner-predictions-2019-trnd/index.html

Comment: “We’re finally in 2019” — I for one can’t believe it’s taken so long.

Answer (score 30):

## Some of the *Blade Runner* technologies that have come to fruition by 2019 include:

- Giant electronic billboards that show full motion video ads.
- Crosswalk **Walk/Don’t Walk** indicators that include audio prompts for the visually-impaired.
- Self-driving cars (**borderline**).
- Access to police databases from in-car computer.
- Voice-interactive computing (but **not** magical photo enhancement).
- Electronically dimming windows.
- Some aspects of gene engineering and creation of artificial animals (for example, a rat kidney has been 3D printed from stem cells; this is perhaps also **borderline**).
- Video phones.

Comment: `but not magical photo enhancement` — we got that too: https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance